# Ada scheduling in EDF

Tags: scheduled-tasks, ada

For some reason this EDF example doesn't compile. I'm using GNAT I tried it in Windows 8.1, Debian no result.

```
 with Ada.Real_Time, ada.Task_Identification,ada.Dispatching.EDF; use Ada.Real_Time, ada.Task_Identification,ada.Dispatching.EDF; 
Procedure exemple_ordon is
   Task tache_Periodique;

   Task body tache_Periodique is
       Echeance: Time_Span := Milliseconds(30); heure: Time;
   Begin
       heure:= Clock; Set_Deadline(Clock + Echeance);
       Loop 
            heure := heure + Echeance;Delay_Until_And_Set_Deadline(heure,Echeance); 
       end loop;
   End tache_Periodique;
Begin Null; End exemple_ordon ;
```

The error message:

```
gnatmake -d -PC:\Users\Awk\default.gpr exemple_ordon.adb
gcc -c -g -O2 -I- -gnatA C:\Users\Awk\exemple_ordon.adb
Edf is not supported in this configuration
compilation abandoned
gnatmake: "C:\Users\Awk\exemple_ordon.adb" compilation error
```

Comment: is it because you have declared "Task tache_Periodique;" Twice ?

Comment: When the compiler rejects your code it tells you why. Please edit your question to show us the error messages. Who knows, they might say what the problem is.

Comment: no it's not about declartion "Task tache_Periodique;" Twice

Comment: I'v messed up when copying the source sorry

Comment: all you need is the with for EDF; I've edited the question to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message `Edf is not supported in this configuration` tells the story!

I don’t have access to any supported version of GNAT, but the file `a-disedf.ads` (the spec of `Ada.Dispatching.EDF`) in FSF GCC 4.9.0 contains the comment

```
--  This unit is not implemented in typical GNAT implementations that lie on
--  top of operating systems, because it is infeasible to implement in such
--  environments.

--  If a target environment provides appropriate support for this package,
--  then the Unimplemented_Unit pragma should be removed from this spec and
--  an appropriate body provided.
```

so it’s possible that AdaCore may provide an implementation for some of the more real-time targets (e.g. VxWorks) for their paying customers.

Do you have access to AdaCore’s academic program (GAP)?

If you really need EDF scheduling, *Concurrency in Ada* by Burns and Wellings has an example (I have the paperback second edition); you can pick it up cheaply at AbeBooks.

If you ‘just’ need information about general tasking, there are several sources listed at the [Ada Information Clearinghouse](http://www.adaic.org/learn/materials/).

Many people developing high-integrity real time software in Ada use the [Ravenscar Profile](http://www.dit.upm.es/~str/ork/documents/RP_ug.pdf).

Comment: No, I just started learning Ada to do some RT application. Because I've heard it's great for that kind thing

Comment: What I'm suppose to do?

Comment: I added some notes at the end of the answer.